# Немного неверный средний цвет (используется np.mean)

Tags: python, изображения, numpy, rgb

Я написал скрипт, который выводит средний цвет картинки в файл. Но, почему-то, значения *немного* неверные.

```py
# coding=utf-8

from __future__ import print_function
import cv2, sys, os
import numpy as np

palette = []

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print(u'Перетащите файл на меня.')
    print(u'(Нажмите Enter для завершения)',end='')
    raw_input()
    sys.exit()

if not os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
    print(u'Неверное имя файла.')
    print(u'(Нажмите Enter для завершения)',end='')
    raw_input()
    sys.exit()
for file in sys.argv[1:]:
    im = cv2.imread(file)
    if im is None:
        print(u'Указанный файл повреждён или не является картинкой.')
        print(u'(Нажмите Enter для завершения)',end='')
        raw_input()
        sys.exit()

    colors = np.unique(im.reshape(-1, im.shape[2]), axis=0)
    color = np.flip(colors.mean(axis=0,dtype=np.float64).astype(int)).tolist()
    palette.append([color,os.path.basename(file)[:-4]])
palette = np.array(palette)
palette = palette[palette[:,0].argsort(kind='mergesort')]
out = open('palette.txt','w')
out.write(str(palette.tolist()))
out.close()
```

Пример: [image: Текстура из Minecraft] - в Photoshop и [тут](https://matkl.github.io/average-color/), средний цвет - [105, 99, 89], но мой скрипт выводит [107,100,90]

Answer (score 1):

Я нашёл ошибку - надо было просто убрать `np.unique()`, и всё заработало как надо!